# how to determine the domain of a logistic function

Tags: functions

I have these two data sets:

```
a={-9.21034037198, -6.90775527898, -4.60517018599, -2.30258509299, 0.,     2.30258509299, 4.60517018599, 6.90775527898, 9.21034037198}
```

and

```
log$\omega$= {0.50000, 0.50000, 0.49970, 0.48471, 0.43806, 0.41499, 0.40731,
0.40486, 0.40409}
```

when I plot these two versus each other I get
[image]
which is similar to a logistic function which has the following form according Wikipedia
$$
f(x)=\frac{L}{1+e^{-k(x-x_0)}}
$$

where

$x_{0}$: the $x$ value of the sigmoid's midpoint;

$L$: the curve's maximum value;

$k$: the logistic growth rate or steepness of the curve

So I think that how I can write the appropriate logistic function for my data. I tried this
$$
f(x)=\frac{0.5}{1+e^{k(x-0.44)}}
$$
but this is not true. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\quad f(x)=\frac{L}{1+e^{-k(x-x_0)}}\quad$ cannot be fitted correctly to the data because an additional term is missing.

More general form of logistic function :
$$f(x)=a+\frac{b}{1+c\:e^{-p\:x}}$$
with $\quad L=b\quad;\quad p=k \quad;\quad x_0=\frac{1}{k}\ln(c).\quad$
The fitted curve is drawn in red.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The logistic function is a sigmoidal, "S" shape, but yours is reflected across the y-axis, so you need to put a negative sign in front of the $x$. Let $x_0$ be the $x$ value of the sigmoid's midpoint, which is around $-1$. We get the function $$f(x)=\frac{.5}{1+e^{-k\left(-(x-(-1))\right)}}$$

Letting $k=1$, we can plot the following graph

[image]

Code used:

```
logistic=Vectorize(function(x) {
  .5 / (1+exp(-1 * (-(x-(-1)))))
})
x=seq(-10, 10, length=1000)
y=logistic(x)
plot(x, y, type="n")
lines(x, y)
abline(v=0)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this obviously does not simulate my data sets! my midpoint must be 0.44, also I should specify k so that the values of $f(x)$ change from 0.5 to 0.4

Comment: No, this does not use your data at all. Note the $x_0$ midpoint refers to the $x$-value of the sigmoid's midpoint, which is not $.44$ (which would be the $y$-value), but $-1$. Right?

Comment: But as I mentioned in my question I need an appropriate logistic function which simulates my data. In fact I don't know how to customize the logistic function for my data sets. Yes sorry my $x_0$ midpoint is about -1.